# The specified deps.json [C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].deps.json] does not exist

Tags: entity-framework-core

Setting up EF Core in a separate project from the main ASP.Net Core project causes Add-Migration to fail with the error `The specified deps.json [C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].deps.json] does not exist`.

*Note: I have substituted root folder with [Solution], startup project with [startupproject] and further down database project with [databaseproject].*

In short I have 3 projects set up as described [here](https://blog.tedd.no/2019/06/20/ef-core-in-separate-project/):

1. ASP.Net Core web api, this is the startup project (`[startpproject]`)
2. Entity Framework Core database, contains the DbContext (`[databaseproject]`)
3. Shared project for models (`[modelsproject]`)

Since the dbcontext is in a different project than the startup project I need to add `-StartupProject` and `-Project` parameters to both `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`.

```
Add-Migration "Initial" -StartupProject MyWebApiProject -Project MyDatabaseProject
Update-Database -StartupProject MyWebApiProject -Project MyDatabaseProject
```

`Add-Migration` gives error described above. If I execute `Add-Migration` with `-Verbose` parameter the output before the error is:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec 
>   --depsfile C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].deps.json 
>   --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\xx.nuget\packages 
>   --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" 
>   C:\Users\xx.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.1\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll 
>   migrations add Initial --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output 
>   --assembly C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject]\[databaseproject].dll 
>   --startup-assembly C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].dll 
>   --project-dir C:\[solution]\[databaseproject]\ 
>   --language C# 
>   --working-dir C:\[solution] 
>   --root-namespace [databaseproject]

The main takeaway here is `--depsfile C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].deps.json`.

Looking for deps.json in solution: `gci *.deps.json -r | select -prop FullName`

> ### FullName
>
> C:\[solution]\[databaseproject]\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DNB.BI.AAC.DataVault.Database.deps.json
>   C:\[solution]\[modelsproject]\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0[modelsproject].deps.json
>   C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1[startupproject].deps.json

There is no `C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].deps.json`. It is put under the build output directory.

None of the other questions (and answers) about deps.json seems to cover this scenario. Although I have a workaround it makes it a bit fiddly to run migrations. I've added the workaround (copying files manually) as an answer to this question.

Is there any other (better) approach / fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying only `C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\[startupproject].deps.json` to `C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].deps.json` does not help, gives new error of missing [databaseproject].dll.

However copying all files/folders (not overwriting anything such as appsettings*.json and property-folder) from build output `C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\` to `C:\[solution]\[startupproject]` makes both Add-Migration and Update-Database work just fine. The copied files can and should be deleted afterwards.

Note that project has to be rebuilt before `Add-Migration`and again before `Update-Database`.

Comment: It is a workaround, thanks. But I do not understand why dotnet is looking for the deps.json file in the root folder. We have two machines with the same repository cloned. One is working ok and the other has this same problem. It started with .NET Core 5.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy contents from bin/debug/netcorex.x/

And Paste those in project root folder and apply ef commands.

Comment: That's what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60184461/861716) already said.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a reliable solution for that problem.

Please check your Release folder and copy all dll's to Debug folder.

C:[solution][startupproject]\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\

to

C:[solution][startupproject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\

and all dotnet ef dbcontext commands will work.

Comment: *There is no C:\[solution]\[startupproject]\[startupproject].deps.json*. After your suggested action it's still not there. Moreover, most of the times there won't be anything in the release folder.

Comment: My problem was that I've ran my project in Release before migration

Comment: Doesn't matter for my remark.