# deps.json does not exist in Entity Framework Core 7 in .NET MAUI app

Tags: entity-framework-core, maui

I am trying to create a migration in an MAUI app.

```
PM> dotnet ef migrations add Init
Build started...
Build succeeded.
dotnet : The specified deps.json [C:\github\Wa1gonGate\LogGate\bin\Debug\net7.0-android\LogGate.deps.json] does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef migrations add Init
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The specified d... does not exist:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I would really like to have my repo classes in a different project.  Is that possible?

Suggestions on this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The specified deps.json [...] does not exist

This is a known issue: [The specified deps.json file doesn't exist #22247](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22247), and [the comment](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22247#issuecomment-1448750437) in it said:

> There is a path bug here. The deps file is looked for in the path `bin\<Platform>\<TargetFramework>\<TargetFramework>\<Runtime>\`
>
> Note the two occurrences of `TargetFramework` and the absence of
> `Configuration`. My outdir is supposed to be
> `bin\<Platform>\<Configuration>\<TargetFramework>\<Runtime>` as
> specified in my `csproj`. This command needs to look for the file in the
> same output folder that msbuild builds to, but it is not.
>
> Note that I am doing this with the command line tools (`dotnet ef migrations`). I updated from version 5 to version 7.0.3 and still
> encounter this bug.
>
> Copying the output folder to the specified directory is a workaround,
> though you will have to remember to keep copying it if you need to
> make changes.

In Addition, I also found this case: [The specified deps.json [...] does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184460/the-specified-deps-json-c-solution-startupproject-startupproject-deps-js). Wish it can help you.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I don't really expect to need migrations in this project.  So I will follow this issue.  I am also thinking I could create a dummy console app to the migrations.