# MyApp.deps.json not found using command "dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate"

Tags: entity-framework-core, maui

I wanted to switch my .NET MAUI App (.net 7) from using SQLite to EF Core to use migrations to get Updates of my App handled more easily.

Therefore, I added the following NuGet-Packages in my csproj:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.14" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.14">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.14" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="7.0.14" />
```

**My csproj looks like this**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios;net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>My App</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.MyApp</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>42a7bc41-46c4-478-9d6a-af3479e68c63</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
      <EnableAssemblyILStripping>false</EnableAssemblyILStripping>
      <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Created via API (AEGHV5562R)</CodesignKey>
      <CodesignProvision>VS: WildCard Development</CodesignProvision>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" />
        
        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!='net7.0-ios'">
      <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png" Color="#000000" BaseSize="1024,1024" Resize="false" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\mo_splash.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
        <InterfaceDefinition Include="LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
        <BundleResource Include="Resources\Images\mo_splash.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="5.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="LocalizationResourceManager.Maui" Version="1.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.14">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="7.0.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.14">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Refractored.MvvmHelpers" Version="1.6.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Sharpnado.CollectionView.Maui" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Sharpnado.Tabs.Maui" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.141-beta" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.7" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Help.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\MainPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\ManageItem.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Settings.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Views\BackgroundImageView.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Views\ItemCompositionView.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Solver\Solver\Solver\Solver.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Maui.Controls.BottomSheet-main\src\Maui.Controls.BottomSheet\Maui.Controls.BottomSheet.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync\SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\SQLiteNetExtensions\SQLiteNetExtensions.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Pages\Views\BackgroundImageView.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>BackgroundImageView.xaml</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
      <Compile Update="Resources\Localization\AppResources.Designer.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Localization\AppResources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EditorConfigFiles Remove="D:\Programming\C#\MyApp\MyApp\.editorconfig" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="D:\Programming\C#\MyApp\MyApp\.editorconfig" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I migrated my Models to EF Core and added a DatabaseContext-File. My Models are located under "Database\Models", my DatabaseContext unter "Database".

I've built my App and restored all packages successfully.

In the "Package Manager Console" I've set my Project as Startup-Project and also within my solution it is set as the Startup-Project.

Executing the following command, I get the error below:

```cs
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

**Error**:

Sometimes it mentions it for iOS, but also for Android

```cs
PM> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Build started...
Build succeeded.
dotnet : The specified deps.json [D:\Programming\C#\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\MyApp.deps.json] does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The specified d... does not exist:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I've also tried with a new Console-Project (.net 7) and added all my Models and DatabaseContext classes to it. **There, it works without errors** and is not complaining about a missing deps.json file. I can also locate the correspondig *.deps.json in my output folder.

On the internet I found hints to delete packages folder and get all of them again => did not work.

I also found a hint to set the startup project again. I did within my solution and also within Package Manager Console => did not work.

I it might work work, to copy all of my Models and Datbase Context to this separate Console-Project I created and keep the Namespaces same as in my .NET MAUI App. Then create the migrations as my database changes and copy these migrations to my .NET MAUI project.
But, I am not sure about that due to the *.deps.json file from the Console-Project. It is mentioning .NET Core in here and my output is `<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios;net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>`

```xml
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0": {
      "MacroOptimizerApp/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.14",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "7.0.14",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "7.0.14",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core": "7.0.14"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "MyApp.dll": {}
        }
      },
      ...
}
```

So far, I have no clue why my *.deps.json is missing and what I can do to execute the `dotnet ef migrations add ...` command successfully. Are there any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About this error, you can refer to my previous answer in this case: [deps.json does not exist in Entity Framework Core 7 in .NET MAUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957425/deps-json-does-not-exist-in-entity-framework-core-7-in-net-maui-app):

This is a known issue: [The specified deps.json file doesn't exist #22247](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22247), and [the comment](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22247#issuecomment-1448750437) in it said:

> There is a path bug here. The deps file is looked for in the path `bin\<Platform>\<TargetFramework>\<TargetFramework>\<Runtime>\`
>
> Note the two occurrences of `TargetFramework` and the absence of
> `Configuration`. My outdir is supposed to be
> `bin\<Platform>\<Configuration>\<TargetFramework>\<Runtime>` as
> specified in my `csproj`. This command needs to look for the file in the
> same output folder that msbuild builds to, but it is not.
>
> Note that I am doing this with the command line tools (`dotnet ef migrations`). I updated from version 5 to version 7.0.3 and still
> encounter this bug.
>
> Copying the output folder to the specified directory is a workaround,
> though you will have to remember to keep copying it if you need to
> make changes.

And also this case: [The specified deps.json [...] does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184460/the-specified-deps-json-c-solution-startupproject-startupproject-deps-js).

Comment: I don’t know if I got it right, but it just said it is looking in a wrong directory. In my .NET MAUI Project, it seems I even do not get a deps.json file at all when looking for it. The only workaround that worked for me now is using a pure .NET Class Library Project and putting my models and DbContext class there to get the migrations. There was a downside then, as I could not specify the connection string with a FileSystem.AppsDirectory in this library project, as the above comes from MAUI and could not be referenced correctly, even with some additional NuGets to get this referenced.

Comment: The above could finally be solved by just providing the FileSystem.AppsDirectory from the .NET MAUI project I reference this class library, but it is not that nice to be honest. In the case where I tried to get the .NET MAUI NuGets in my new Database Class Library project, I got another error with missing things when I used ```dotnet ef migrations …```. To me it appeared like it is not working with MAUI other than the Class Library workaround. Strange thing they don’t fix that bug when it is existing for so long time - it is an important command and not useable like this

Comment: *Strange thing they don’t fix that bug when it is existing for so long time - it is an important command and not useable like this* Yes, it is. [MAUI issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8114) move it to dotnet/efcore. However, as you can see the last reply saying: This should be reported on the SDK repo: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk. Not Planned. Move it to dotnet/sdk again.

Comment: But I didn’t see anything related in [dotnet/sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) :(   If you're willing, you can report one on it.

Comment: I read over your link and posts, but could not find a solution in there or did I overlook it? The threads describe the different misbehaviors  right now. I think the "solution" right now is really to have the projects separated and use a .NET 7 compilation so that the ```dotnet ef migrations ...``` command works. Your answer is still the answer as it describes and links really good all these misbehaviors