# How to provide parameters to a ViewModel or access a registered Service in a ViewModel to get a registered service instance

Tags: maui

I have a .NET MAUI App in which I registered a new service in my MauiProgram.cs

```cs
...
var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();
...
```

I added this DatabaseContext to the Constructor of my **MainPage**:

```cs
private DatabaseContext _databaseContext;

public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel, DatabaseContext dbContext)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _databaseContext = dbContext;

    mainPageViewModel = viewModel;
    BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

In XAML of the MainPage I need access to 2 different ViewModels. The one that belongs to the MainPage (MainPageViewModel) and also access to **CalculateViewModel** which is referenced in the ContentPage.Resources as can be seen in the example below.

I also added the DatabaseContext to parameters of the CalculateViewModel. But now, in XAML of the MainPage it says that it can't access CalculateViewModel as there is no parameterless Constructor available.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages.Views"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
             xmlns:tabs="http://sharpnado.com"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XGENO.Maui.Controls;assembly=Maui.Controls.BottomSheet"
             x:DataType="viewModels:MainPageViewModel"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.MainPage"
             Title="{Binding MainPageTitle}">


    <!-- Style for BottomTabs -->
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        ...
        <viewModels:CalculateViewModel x:Key="CalculateViewModel" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="MainPageViewGrid" RowDefinitions="*, 55">

            <!-- Switcher to switch between the different Views -->
            <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="ContentViewSwitcher"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Animate="True"
                               SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedViewModelIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <tabs:DelayedView x:TypeArguments="views:CalculateView"
                                  BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}}"
                                  AccentColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                                  Animate="True"                              
                                  UseActivityIndicator="True" />


            </tabs:ViewSwitcher>
                

            <!-- Tabs at the Bottom -->
            <tabs:TabHostView Grid.Row="1"
                              BackgroundColor="White"
                              Orientation="Horizontal"
                              TabType="Fixed"
                              SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentViewSwitcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
                    

                    <tabs:TabButton x:Name="CalculateAddCircleButton"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    ButtonCircleSize="110"
                                    IconImageSource="circle_plus_solid_orange.png"
                                    TapCommand="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}, Path=DisplayBottomSheetCommand}"
                                    TranslationY="-15" />

                </tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
            </tabs:TabHostView>
        </Grid>


        <controls:BottomSheet x:Name="BottomSheet"
                              HeaderText="{loc:Translate BottomSheet_AddToMealHeader}"
                              HeaderStyle="{StaticResource BottomSheetHeaderStyle}"
                              BottomSheetClosed="BottomSheet_Closed"
                              InputTransparent="True">

            <!-- Content of the BottomSheet is defined in a separate View:  BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent -->
            <controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent>
                <views:BottomSheetContentView BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}}" />
            </controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent>

        </controls:BottomSheet>
        
    </Grid>
    

</ContentPage>
```

How can I solve this? Problem is that due to the resource structure of the MainPage.xaml it needs to construct the CalculateViewModel, but this obviously does not allow to have other constructors than the default constructor here. I also tried to get the CalculateViewModel via Resources["CalculateViewModel"] and then provide my DatabaseContext via Property from MainPage. But in MainPage Constructor there needs to `InitializeComponent();` first and there is already some access needed to the DatabaseContext which is not available then.

Question, how would I solve this or how is this normally done in .NET MAUI?

Comment: Are you asking how Dependency Injection works in MAUI?

Comment: Well, I must admit, in this particular case, yes. In InitializeComponent the ViewModel with the dbContext is already needed. The only idea I have that might work is creating the ViewModel with the dbContext before InitializateComponent and try to set the ViewModel in XAML as n the Contentpage.Respurces with a ```Source=„{x:Static local:MainPage.ViewModelInstance}“```. Hope this could work. But is it the supposed way for something like that, or is there a way that is better?

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design. A ViewModel is to seperate the business logic for the View, who is responsible for the user interaction. If you need to access another Views ViewModel ie data, you do that through a Service. So you need a service that both of the ViewModels can use. Normally you have a data layer service that has access to the dbcontext. It is all about seperations of duties. Does this make sense.

Comment: Yes it does make sense in a way. It makes sense to have a service that can be used from both classes. I thought such a service is registered like I did with ```builder.Services.AddDbContext()``` for instance. I don’t know how I could access this services from any class in the system, other transporting it via dependency injection via constructor which then does not work with what I have in XAML. Do you have a code example from a different project that shows how I should realize such a thing here? I am with you that it seems kind of mixed that information is shared between different ViewModels

Comment: The first two lines of code you're showing don't make sense and I'm pretty certain `builder.Services.AddDbContext()` doesn't exist in MAUI.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using the MS Entity Framework. At least in IntelliSense I could see the AddDbContext<…>() - The problem with this was, that I wanted to use EF Migrations and it seems to be not possible mixing it with .NET MAUI to generate the migrations (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540967/myapp-deps-json-not-found-using-command-dotnet-ef-migrations-add-initialcreate). So, I instantiated my DbContext class there to assign it the FileSystem.AppsDataDirectory from MAUI.

Comment: @Julian - solved this so that the new DatabaseContext() is not necessary anymore. The line ```build.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>()``` is possible and still there. Unfortunately, I have to create a new instance of a ViewModel in Code and there constructor dependency injection does not work.

Comment: The `AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>()` extension must be provided by EF then, it's not shipped with MAUI. Apart from that, I think Stephen Quan's answer gets close to what you need based on your question.

Comment: @PeterWessberg - this was also an option to get a Service ```var settingsService = this.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetServices<ISettingsService>();``` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection what do you think about using this in cases when I have to create a ViewModel in Code and need to provide the ```DatabaseContext``` there?

Comment: To use  ˋGetServices<T> is a normal way to get your service from the DI container. It is always best to use DI through your Constructor, and in my opinion shows that your code is sound, but don’t hesitate to use GetService<T> if needed. The importen is that you has good separation of concerns in your code and use it as you say from your ViewModel and not from your view. Still, to make it clear, anyone can do whatever they want but I like my SOLID architecture.

Comment: As you mentioned in your question to which I replied, there is still a risk something is not correctly in place and it is good you mentioned that point. As the Code grows there is a higher risk for that and it reminded me to check again. I still have problems to bind everything correctly over different files so that UI and what you have to connect over different Views and therefore ViewModels gets updated correctly. Still also a problem to have Constructor DI when using ViewModels in UI. I came across the problem that a ViewModel could not be created correctly used in XAML with constructor DI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making sure you know, the dependency injection should have your `MainPage` and view models also set up:

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CalculateViewModel>();
```

Just declare `CalculateViewModel` as a dependency of `MainPageViewModel`

```cs
// MainPageViewModel.cs
public MainPageViewModel()
{
    CalculateViewModel Calculate { get; }
    public MainPageViewModel(CalculateViewModel Calculate)
    {
        this.Calculate = Calculate;
    }
}
```

So your `MainPage` now has access to all of the `MainPageViewModel` properties and, it has access to the `CalculateViewModel` via the `Calculate` property.

In a similar vein, you could move the constructor injection parameter for `DatabaseContext` from `MainPage` to `MainPageViewModel`, it's up to you.